# Highchart Annotation Scroll

Tags: highcharts, annotations

I have to resize the annotation label size(div) based on the annotation text height (span). I have attached the screenshot by removing the CSS of text but its overlapped the border/label size. Is there any option to dynamically update the SVG element height based on the inner text(Span).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Wgj.png]

Comment: Can you please add in your current code with what you tried so far?

Comment: Could you prepare online example of your chart/app or send the code with chart options? Annotations lables should dynamically set height based on inner element, check here http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/048m2qxz/.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **useHTML** option and apply proper CSS styles:

```
.highcharts-annotation-label > span {
    height: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8bwe70y5/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.useHTML

Comment: I am using useHTML to display the chart but when exporting to PNG I need the complete annotation text to be displayed.

Comment: Hi user3129206, after exporting all annotation text is displayed. You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pr4qzdLt/

Comment: Thanks Dear, With the inbuilt HighChart Export to PNG functionality I am able to get the annotation without scroll but I am facing this issue when using query selector of the document to export high chart graph & adding header & footer on the server side.

Comment: So to solve this issue, you can toggle styles responsible for annotation scrollbar before and after exporting.